# JQuery Post Data Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mobile, http-post

I am trying to get data from a form submit. Here is the code.

```
function codeSubmission() {
$("#questionCodeForm").submit(function() {
    $.post("SubmitCode.php", $("#questionCodeForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {
        var questionName = data.questionName,
            options = data.options,
            pollingStatus = data.pollingStatus,
            codeExist = data.codeExist;

        alert(data);
        alert(data[1])
        alert(questionName);
        alert(options);

        if(codeExist == true) {
            $("#quizTitle").text("questionName");

            for(rowNum=1;rowNum<=5;rowNum++) {
                $("#checkbox-"+rowNum).val("Answer1");
                $("#checkbox"+rowNum+"label").text("Answer"+rowNum);
            } 

            $("#answerForm").slideDown(500);
        } else if(codeExist == false) {
            alert("This quiz code is invalid");
        }   
    });
    return false;   
});
return false;
}
```

Now the problem is that I cannot get the data into the variables I want. Furthermore I think the data is being sent as a string rather than an array. Here is the output of alert(data) for debugging purposes

> {"questionName":"Test","pollingStatus":"0","options":  {"1":"Test7","2":"Test8","3":"Test9","4":"Test10","5":"Test11"},"codeExist":true}

Now the above output from the jsonencode seems right. However to see the problem here is the output of data[0].

> {

So I think the jsonencode is returning as a string. What I want to be able to do is access the data like questionName. How do I do this? Please help if you can.

Comment: well of course it's returning as a string, JSON is the notation that would represent an object...in string format. The issue here is that `$.post()` doesn't decode the JSON Object being sent back, so you'll need to `$.parseJSON(data)` to get what you want.

Comment: so instead of $.post I write $.parseJson?

Comment: You can use either answer mentioned below, as passing `json` as a string to the $.post method, will tell it to use `$.parseJSON()` on the `returnData`, or you can do, `returnData = $.parseJSON(returnData);`

Comment: So how exactly do I implement this syntax-wise. (I'm fairly new to jQuery so I dont know where to put what).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OhGodWhy posted above, you also have to parse the json on the client side. You can do this using

obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Answer (score 1):

You can tell jQuery to use the "json" data-Type:

```
$.post('url', postData, function(returnData) {
  alert(returnData.question);
}, 'json');
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: The problem is that when I put in the 'json' the page keeps refreshing so I cannot see the alerts.